# Is it possible to use ref types in C# built-in Action<> delegate?

Tags: c#

C# has built-in delegates `Action<>` and `Func<>`. Is it possible to use 'ref' type parameters for this delegates? For example, this code:

```
public delegate void DTest( ref Guid a );
public event DTest ETest;
```

Will compile. But if I use `Action<>`, it will not compile:

```
public event Action< ref Guid > ETest;
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

No, you can't use pass-by-reference with the `Action` delegates. While there is a concept of "type passed by reference" as a `Type` in the framework, it's not really a type in the normal sense as far as C# is concerned. `ref` is a modifier for the parameter, not part of the type name, if you see what I mean.

However, you can build your own set of equivalent types, e.g.

```
delegate void ActionRef<T>(ref T item);
```

Of course, if you want a mixture of ref and non-ref parameters in the same delegate, you get into a horrible set of combinations:

```
delegate void ActionRef1<T1, T2>(ref T1 arg1, T2 arg2);
delegate void ActionRef2<T1, T2>(T1 arg1, ref T2 arg2);
delegate void ActionRef3<T1, T2>(ref T1 arg1, ref T2 arg2);
```

Comment: is this the only to define with lamda syntax?  ActionRef<int, int> Setter2 = (ref int x, int y) =>x = y;  It's fine... but just a little longer than normal.

Comment: @sgtz: I suspect so - it's a pretty unusual requirement, so I'm not surprised if there hasn't been much work to make it concise.

Comment: how about "ref R[i]" where R is a List<T>.  Is this possible?  Would you like me to pose this as a new question?

Comment: Hi Jon, has anything changed in that regard in C# 7? Because I used (in a C# 6 project) Action<ref Foo> and got an error from R# saying it's a C# 7 feature. Is it a mistake on their end?

Comment: @gdoron: Not that I'm aware. There's plenty of new stuff in terms of `ref` in C# 7, but not that...

Answer (score 8):

You can as long as your reference is a complex object (has properties).

Example object:

```
public class MyComplexObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Name provided for the result.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Value of the result.
    /// </summary>
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Used in an Action:

```
Action<MyComplexObject> myAction = (MyComplexObject result) =>
{
    result.Value = MyMethodThatReturnsSomething();                                              
};
```

Since the MyComplexObject reference is not changed, the data is preserved.

Also [posted on my blog](http://xcalibur37.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/c-how-to-pass-object-references-into-actions/).

Comment: It's not really an answer to the question considering this allocates an object. If someone is using `ref` they must have had a reason to pass by reference...

Comment: -1 Classes are refs regardless of whether they have properties. And the question is about Actions with ref parameters (which are probably not objects), which this doesn't answer--wrapping a class around a property is not the same thing at all.