# Performing an action for each element in a 2D array

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm currently working on a game where the background is represented by a 2D array of tiles. Tile is a relatively simple class that contains graphic and traversability information. In my code, I find myself wanting to do something similar to the following often:

```
for (int x = 0; x < TileMap.GetLength(0); x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < TileMap.GetLength(1); y++)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Obviously there's a better way to do that, right? I thought that maybe I could create an extension method that takes an Action parameter that iterates through the array and performs the specified action for each Tile, like so:

```
public static void PerformAction(this Tile[,] tileMap, Action<Tile> action)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < tileMap.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < tileMap.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            action(tileMap[x, y]);
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this (just an example):

```
TileMap.PerformAction(t => t = new Tile());
```

This doesn't work, though. I can set a breakpoint in either the extension method or in the lambda expression and watch it get hit each iteration, but the actual Tile in the TileMap remains unchanged. For the example above, all Tiles are still null if they were null before. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to do what I want to do?

Comment: You're just modifying the value of the argument. You need to add the `ref` modifier if you expect to be able to modify the actual reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like you want to be able to modify the element in the array itself, not just the object it references (or value it stores…it's not clear whether `Tile` is a `class` or a `struct`). Of course, invoking an `Action<T>` delegate, you're just passing the value from the array to the method, not a reference to the element of the array. The delegate has no way to modify the array itself in that scenario.

One way to fix this is to pass the element of the array by-reference instead of the default by-value. The built-in delegate types don't support by-reference parameter passing. But you can declare your own delegate (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1707325/3538012) for more details):

```
delegate void ActionRef<T>(ref T t);
```

Then you can implement your extension method like this:

```
public static void PerformAction(this Tile[,] tileMap, ActionRef<Tile> action)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < tileMap.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < tileMap.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            action(ref tileMap[x, y]);
        }
    }
}
```

Passing a delegate from a method like this:

```
void MyActionMethod(ref Tile tile)
{
    // do something to tile
}
```

An alternative approach (and IMHO maybe somewhat cleaner) would be to have the action delegate return a new value if desired:

```
public static void PerformAction(this Tile[,] tileMap, Func<Tile, Tile> action)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < tileMap.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < tileMap.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            tileMap[x, y] = action(tileMap[x, y]);
        }
    }
}
```

Then your method might look something like this:

```
Tile MyActionMethod(Tile tile)
{
    // do something to tile

    return tile;
}
```