# Modification of a list's elements with ForEach statement

Tags: c#, list, lambda

I've stumbled upon a `List<T>` behaviour that I'm not quite sure I can understand.
I have the following example code

```
List<int> myInts = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
myInts.ForEach( x => x += 1);
```

The list however, remains unchanged after the ForEach statement. Can someone explain to me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` is a [value type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), which means when the lambda function in the `ForEach` is called, a copy of the `int` value is passed, rather than the lambda having a reference available to the original value.  It is this copy that is being modified, not the original value in the list.

If you wish to modify the list, you either need to loop through the list modifying each entry individually, or return and assign a new list with the updated values:

```
//loop through and modify:
for (var x = 0; x < myInts.Count; x++)
    myInts[x] += 1;

//or use Select to construct a new list:
myInts = myInts.Select(x => x += 1).ToList();
```

Comment: You'll the same problem with reference types. You could only change the content of an object. A call like 'ForEach(x => x = new object())' won't change the list content. Yes x is a pointer to reference types instance but the pointer itself is a value type and the lambda gets a copy of it.

Comment: @Verarind Indeed - and you [can't use `ref` parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1707325/791010) with the `Action<T>` that `ForEach` requires, so if you want to be modifying things in this way, you have to use one of the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

James Thorpe's answer is totally correct, but I'd like to elaborate on what the *difference* between `ForEach` and `Select` on `IEnumerable` is.

**ForEach**

This should be used when you want to use a block lambda (meaning more than just a single expression like most lambda expressions).  Generally speaking, this is not heavily used (for the reason you've experienced); you're better off just using a `foreach` block.

**Select**

This is for **projecting** the contents of an `IEnumerable` into another form; meaning it's *exactly* what you're looking for.  It should be used when you want to go through each element and transform the contents into something else.