# My c# custom delegate behaves weird (No overload for <X> matches <my custom delegate>)

Tags: c#, function, exception, delegates, ref

Okay, so after reading into creating custom function delegates after [Func<> didnt accept a ref keyword inside the type declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707310/is-it-possible-to-use-ref-types-in-c-sharp-built-in-action-delegate), I ended up with this delegate:

```
private delegate TResult RefFunc<T, out TResult>(ref T arg);
```

inside my little test project. I also declared these two functions:

```
private static string FirstFunction(string arg) {
    return "";
}
private static string SecondFunction(string arg) {
    return "";
}
```

*(Since I discovered the problem, this truly is the only function content!)*
that adhere to the above delegate and are passed as parameters to this function:

```
private static void SampleFunction(RefFunc<String, String> argOne, RefFunc<String, String> argTwo) { ... }
```

Like so (simplified):

```
private static void Main(string[] args) {
    SampleFunction(FirstFunction, SecondFunction);
}
```

That function call wouldn't work out because "`Conversion of 'method group' to '<class>.RefFunc<string, string>' isn't possible`", which makes sense - I'm directly passing a function without turning it into a delegate first - although I'm pretty sure I've seen that same syntax working with the Action<> Delegate somewhere. Anyways, I then modified my caller code in the Main() function in many ways while looking into the issue, however none of the below approaches resolved the issue.

```
SampleFunction(new RefFunc<String, String>(FirstFunction), ...); // Causes "No overload for FirstFunction matches delegate RefFunc<string, string>" at the first function parameter
SampleFunction(RefFunc FirstFunction, ...); // Was worth a try
RefFunc handler = FirstFunction; SampleFunction(handler, ...); // As described in docs. Causes "The usage of type "RefFunc<T, TResult>" (generic) requires 2 type arguments" at keyword RefFunc
RefFunc<String, String> handler = FirstFunction; SampleFunction(handler, ...); // Didn't help it. Causes the same error as with the first attempt
// and a few others
```

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/using-delegates)
I've finally decided to turn to stackoverflow. Since my functions clearly adhere to the delegate I created, I can't really understand why C# believes they do not. I appreciate any help!
*Please note that while I'm only showing code relevant to the error caused, the project is very small, so I'm sure the problem doesn't lie elsewhere*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since my functions clearly adhere to the delegate I created

Unfortunately, neither of your `FirstFunction` and `SecondFunction` is of `RefFunc` type, just because the `T` is passed by `ref` in the delegate's defintion and in the same time you lack `ref` in your actual functions.

Either you modify both functions

```
public class Program
{
    private delegate TResult RefFunc<T, out TResult>(ref T arg);

    private static string FirstFunction(ref string arg) {
       return "";
    }
    private static string SecondFunction(ref string arg) {
       return "";
    }

    private static void SampleFunction(
        RefFunc<String, String> argOne, RefFunc<String, String> argTwo) 
    { 
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        SampleFunction(FirstFunction, SecondFunction);
    }
}
```

or you drop `ref`

```
private delegate TResult RefFunc<T, out TResult>(T arg);
```

which now is a correct type for

```
private static string SecondFunction(string arg) {
    return "";
}
```