# Call thread by reference (.Net)

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, reference, pass-by-reference

The following does not work because `Sub(ByRef t As T) ...` Is not an `Action(Of T)` because it recieves its argument `ByRef`. This means that the following code that appempts to call a thread with a value `ByRef` does not work.

```vb
Public Sub UseLater(Of T As Structure)(ByRef t As T, m As Mutex, callback As [Delegate]) 'Includes ByRef Consumer
  m.WaitOne()
  m.ReleaseMutex()
  callback(t)
End Sub

''...

  Dim getterLock As New Mutex()
  Dim buffer As MyType = Nothing
  Dim threadhelper As [Delegate] = Sub(ByRef t As MyType) ''ISSUE: Action arg cannot be ByRef
                                     UseLater(Of MyType)(t, getterLock, Sub(ByRef t_ As MyType) buffer = t_)
                                   End Sub

  getterLock.WaitOne()
  Dim getLater As New Thread(threadhelper)
  getLater.Start(MyObject) ''Currently in scope object
  Dim getter As [Delegate] = Function() As MyType
                               getterLock.ReleaseMutex()
                               Return buffer
                             End Function

''getter can be passed out of scope
```

How can I call a thread with a `ByRef`?
(Or equivilently aquire a getter `Func(Of T)` and a setter `Action(Of T)` from a `ByRef`?)

Comment: So I've been looking at this for a couple hours, I'm probably not going to be giving exact answers any time soon but I'm really curious about your use case here, what exactly is the problem your trying to solve here by passing threads byref?  Perhaps you could up update your question with some real world context?

Comment: I think the only way to make this work is going to be to box the struct into an object.  Also see related C# question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707310/is-it-possible-to-use-ref-types-in-c-sharp-built-in-action-delegate

Comment: @Hursey I tried to make the code minimalistic. I was trying to create a `Accessor` Structure that would allow me to explicitly capture byref when constructing lambdas and allow me to write verbose code, for example: `SharedContainer(Of Accessor(Of T))`.

Comment: @Craig I do know of this solution, I have a `SharedContainer` Class in a Util module in my project but that requires rewriting a lot of code! Using implicit construction (Via convertion) and properties I can effectively store a value ByRef, which minimises rewriting.